# Make pdf reader like functionality in my app (highlight the content)

Tags: iphone, pdf, highlighting

I need a functionality like in the iphone pdf reader.

i want that user select some text content and that content should be highlighted with yellow color.

Currently i am using text view and want to know that can i achieve same functionality in it.
or i have to shift to pdf ?

Please tell that how to achieve that in either of the two.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML)

Comment: i have tried it with xcode 4 on iphone simulator and it worked just fine. what is the error? its not my code i just gave you a reference... but we can still try to resolve it..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView)

A drop-in replacement for UITextView that amongst other things supports attributed strings. This would allow you to achieve your aim of selecting text, and then applying a style to that selection such as a yellow highlight.